# Testing BroadcastChannel API using JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, broadcast-channel

I have implemented cross-browser tab communication using the broadcast channel API in my React Project. It's working as expected in the browser, but I am struggling to write unit tests for it using JEST. When I run the test case, the post message gets called, but the onmessage function never gets called. Can anyone help me?

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('some-name');

channel.onmessage = function(e) {
  // some code
```

}

```
 channel.postMessage({ message: 'some message' });
```

Comment: Hi Asif Iqbal,

I have not yet found how to resolve this and am experiencing the exact same issue.

I have so far tried installing broadcast-channel npm and mocking the polyfill neither fire the listener. It is very frustrating.

Comment: More info https://dev.to/akinncar/how-to-solve-broadcastchannel-is-not-defined-4cjh